# Does anyone know the name of this component?

Tags: components, power-over-ethernet

[image: Image of the component I am wondering the name of.]

I think what this does is give power to the Ethernet cable that is attached to the satellite above the house.

Comment: There is a generic term, but it's not coming to me just now -- something like "power tap".

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because "guessing game" questions aren't a good fit for the site.  The question makes sense only if you look at the picture, so there is no way to index the question or any answers so that it will be useful to others.  See discussion here: http://meta.superuser.com/questions/7647/are-hardware-port-cable-etc-visual-identification-questions-allowed-or-not.

Comment: My apologies. I wasn't sure where to post this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're referring to the small black box with ethernet cable plugged into both sides and a smaller side wire coming off, it appears to be a Power Over Ethernet (PoE) adapter.  With compatible equipment at the other end of the cable, this can power low current draw items from the ethernet cable, thus not requiring any additional power supply.

Comment: It's sometimes called a "power injector" or a "[power over Ethernet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_over_Ethernet) injector" because it injects power into the Ethernet cable.